# On touching marker on Google maps, marker is going away from touched position

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

I am not getting why this issue is happening. Whenever I try to touch the marker it is going away. I don't know what is wrong with below code. This is happening in both Web browser and in build apk for android. Below is my code.

**Map initiation code**

```
initMap() {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
      let latLng = {lat: resp.coords.latitude, lng: resp.coords.longitude};
      this.storage.set('latitude', resp.coords.latitude);
      this.storage.set('longitude', resp.coords.longitude);
      this.initializeCurrent(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15
      }

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

      this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        draggable: true,
        map: this.map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Marker is here.'
      });

      this.marker.addListener('dragend', ($event) => this.onMarkerDrop($event));
      this.loading.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong in the above code. Thank you.

Comment: Isolate the issue first. _Whenever I try to touch the marker it is going away_. Comment out the dragend event, does your marker sit on the page and stay there if you try to do something with it?

Comment: Hi @rags2riches, I removed the dragend event. still issue is persistent.

Comment: Can you just declare your `marker` in a `var` or `let` without using `this`? Tell me the errors that you are getting in the console. Beyond this point I will need to ask for a [self-contained code sample to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `disableAutoPan: true` to the Marker options.